# Execute Stored Procedure in JPA 2.0

Tags: jpa, stored-procedures

I have the following problem and I do not how to solve it.
I have a stored procedure with one parameter ( a date in the format: yyyy-MM-dd ) on my MSSQL Server 2008.
Then I have an @Entity class with a @NamedNativeQuery:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "my_stored_proc",query = "? = exec EMIR_GUI.get_OTCLite_ACKNACK_Report ?", resultClass = EmirFacade.class)
@Entity
public class EmirFacade {   
@Column(name="MessageType", nullable=false)
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private String mesageType;
```

My Bean class looks like this:

```
    @PersistenceContext(unitName=Globals.__TWHUNITNAME)
private EntityManager em;

public List<EmirFacade> get_EmirReport(Date date) {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("my_stored_proc").setParameter(1, date);
        List<EmirFacade> emir_report = q.getResultList();
        //List emir_report = q.getResultList();
        return emir_report;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Now, I always get back the following error message ( it is in german, so I have to translate it as good as I can )
Index "0" is out of range.

I tried nearly everything but I cannot find any way to solve my problem.

Maybe, somebody has a good suggestion for me?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JPA 2.0 has no explicit support for stored procedures (JPA 2.1 has).

One workaround is to use native queries (like `{CALL APURARCAMPANHASBRINDES.PROC_APURARCAMPANHA(?1, ?2, ?3, ?4, ?5, ?6, ?7)}`), but that doesn’t work when the procedure has out-parameters.

Here is a sample implementation that uses Hibernate’s Work interface:

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.jdbc.Work;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@Service
public class CampanhaBrindesStoredProcedure {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private String mensagem;
    private String geroubrinde;

    @Transactional
    public void apurarCampamha(Long numeroPedido, String codigoFilialNF,
         String cgcEntCGCENT, Long numeroSequencia, String integradora)  {
        try {
            MyStoredProc storedProc = new MyStoredProc(numeroPedido, codigoFilialNF, 
                cgcEntCGCENT, numeroSequencia, integradora);
            entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).doWork(storedProc);
            setGeroubrinde(storedProc.getGeroubrinde());
            setMensagem(storedProc.getMensagem());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public String getGeroubrinde() {
        return geroubrinde;
    }

    public void setGeroubrinde(String geroubrinde) {
        this.geroubrinde = geroubrinde;
    }

    public String getMensagem() {
        return mensagem;
    }

    public void setMensagem(String mensagem) {
        this.mensagem = mensagem;
    }

    private static final class MyStoredProc implements Work {

        private final Long numeroPedido;
        private final String codigoFilialNF;
        private final String cgcEntCGCENT;
        private final Long numeroSequencia;
        private final String integradora;
        private String mensagem;
        private String geroubrinde;

        private MyStoredProc(Long numeroPedido, String codigoFilialNF, 
                String cgcEntCGCENT, Long numeroSequencia, String integradora) {
            this.numeroPedido = numeroPedido;
            this.codigoFilialNF = codigoFilialNF;
            this.cgcEntCGCENT = cgcEntCGCENT;
            this.numeroSequencia = numeroSequencia;
            this.integradora = integradora;
        }

        @Override
        public void execute(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
            try (CallableStatement stmt = conn
                    .prepareCall("{CALL APURARCAMPANHASBRINDES.PROC_APURARCAMPANHA(?1, ?2, ?3,  ?4, ?5, ?6, ?7)}")) {
                stmt.setLong(1, numeroPedido);
                stmt.setString(2, codigoFilialNF);
                stmt.setString(3, cgcEntCGCENT);
                stmt.setLong(4, numeroSequencia);
                stmt.setString(5, integradora);
                stmt.registerOutParameter(6, Types.VARCHAR);
                stmt.registerOutParameter(7, Types.VARCHAR);
                stmt.executeUpdate();
                mensagem = stmt.getString(6);
                geroubrinde = stmt.getString(7);
                if (stmt.wasNull()) {
                    geroubrinde = null;
                    mensagem = null;
                }
            }
        }

        public String getMensagem() {
            return mensagem;
        }

        public String getGeroubrinde() {
            return geroubrinde;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can switch to JPA 2.1 (and I strongly suggest you to do so) you can simply do:

```
    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("yourStoredprocedure");
    // set parameters
    storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("parameterName", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
    storedProcedure.setParameter("parameterName", "yourParameter");
    // execute stored procedure        
    storedProcedure.execute();
```

otherwise it's a bit more convoluted, simply follow [this tutorial](http://www.ctmmc.net/how-to-call-stored-procedures).

Comment: Thank you very much, then I have to see how I can integrate JPA 2.1. Trying it the old way, I am also not very familiar with. Since, I am not so used to JPA.With JPA 2.1 I already have the problem to find out how to add it to my project.

Comment: Strange, after having added hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.final.jar to my projekt and copying the StoredProcedureQuery into my code, my entitymanager ( em ) is not having any reference to createStoredProcedureQuery - maybe, it is something else?

Comment: @user3003944 If you use Hibernate as JPA provider since version 4.3 JPA 2.1 is available.

Comment: Thanks to all of you! I was able to solve my problems. I had one API twice, and so weblogic always used the old version.